# Should data objects be considered immutable?

Tags: java

I have defined a data object that maps to the fields stored in DynamoDB table. Whenever I do a load by specifying the class name such as `dynamodbmapper.load(Item.class, hashkey)`. Should I be making the Item class fields final? Conceptually should this object be immutable? I don't want any service code to modify this object.

Comment: Just because the parameter is defined as final by your method, won't make it final in other methods, besides, methods can't change the object reference, which will effect the callers reference anyway

Comment: You can always construct a defensive copy and do not care if outer code does modify object or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you don't want any service code to modify this object then this seems like a good idea in general. Only viable for you if DynamoDB Java library supports creating instances via costructor args only, no direct field access or setters - it may not (I dunno).